# iOS 7 Mail App WIth Gmail: Hide "Promotions"?

Tags: mail.app, gmail, ios

Gmail on the web has "Social" and "Promotions" tabs that filter certain types of messages.  Most of the time, I plan to ignore emails that end up in either of those folders.

On iOS 7 in the Mail app, is it possible to some how sort out "Promotions" and "Social" emails from the main lot, similar to how Gmail does on the web?  I don't like these emails mixed in with my regular inbox (i.e., the important emails).

I am well aware of a couple alternative options (marking "Promotions" and "Social" as spam or unsubscribing from them), but I'm really just looking for a way to sort them out without doing either of those things.

Comment: Mail.app on iOS currently has very limited abilities as far as rules. Have you tried the Gmail.app from the App store? I haven't used it, but it's possible it may support Promotions/Social tabs.

Comment: I was actually considering the Gmail app, but I noticed that the Gmail iPad app had a 2 star rating :(

Answer (score 1):

Try the latest version of Gmail.app for iOS. It now supports promotions/social/forums messages segregated from your "primary" inbox.

Answer (score 0):

Inky mail does the similar work to GMail's: sorts messages into cathegories. However, it uses its own algorithm, not reusing GMail's existing tab sorting (so *might* be less intelligent, but works with any mail).